# Export data into Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to customize my Excel output result with certain columns.  Right now I have the export to excel working okay, but it shows too many columns.  I wanted to just export certain columns.  Any idea how to do it?

```
  public void ExportFilteredHistorydDataToExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            // getting session data from the grid
            var claims = (List<ClaimsArchived>)Session["allclaims"];

            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = claims;
            gv.DataBind();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            //Response.Charset = "";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filteredHistoryClaims.xls");

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            gv.RenderControl(htw);

            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a problem exporting data to Excel Spreadsheet.", ex);
        }
    }
```

and the model

```
public partial class ClaimsArchived
{

    public int Claim_ID { get; set; }
    public String Provider
    {
        get
        {
            if (Provider_Group == 73)
            {
                return "CEP";
            }
            else if (Provider_Group == 72)
            {
                return "CASE";
            }
            else
            {
                return "???";
            }
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Provider Num")]
    public Nullable<int> Provider_Group { get; set; }

    public string Facility { get; set; }
    public string Physician { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last")]
    public string Patient_Last { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First")]
    public string Patient_First { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "DOB")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Patient_DOB { get; set; }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(Patient_DOB);

            int tempage = date.Year - birthday.Year;

            return tempage;
        }
    }

    public string Funding_Type
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(Patient_DOB);

            int compareAge = date.Year - birthday.Year;
            if (compareAge > 20)
            {
                return "MADDY";
            }
            else
            {
                return "RICHIE";
            }
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string Patient_Gender { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  temp remove that from the output and export -- SSNs are sensitive information so that's why disabled in this case 
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "SSN")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:###-##-####}")]
    public Nullable<int> Patient_SSN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string Patient_Zip { get; set; }
    public string Diagnosis { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total Charges")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Total_Charges { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "EMS Rate")]
    public Nullable<decimal> Total_EMS { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    //public bool Paid { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Paid Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Paid_date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unique ID")]
    public Nullable<int> Unique_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Import Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ImportDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Arh Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ArchiveDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Archived")]
    public bool ArchiveYesNo { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to removed the four columns from the Excel like SSN, Import Date, Arch Date, and Archived columns.  Any idea?  Thank you!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Let me try and see what happened!  Thank you!

Comment: Why are you generating an HTML file and serving it with the the MIME type that corresponds to an XLSX file and the file extension of XLS? That's a disaster! Do yourself a favor: generate real Excel files using an actual library like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML, Aspose, or Office XML SDK, and serve them with the correct MIME type  and file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            // hiding the column header -- Added code start here ---
            gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            // hiding the column detail
            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[i];
                row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            }
            // ------------------  Added code ended here ------

            // following code are the same
            gv.RenderControl(htw);

            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```